# Send data to third party with WordPress Gravity Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using the following [code](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_after_submission/) in functions.php to submit to a third party via cURL.
The issue is this code is universal for all my Form Instances (I have countless Gravity Forms on my WP site and I only need one to go to this 3rd party)

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) {

    $post_url = 'http://thirdparty.com';
    $body = array(
        'first_name' => rgar( $entry, '1.3' ), 
        'last_name' => rgar( $entry, '1.6' ), 
        'message' => rgar( $entry, '3' ),
        );

    $request = new WP_Http();
    $response = $request->post( $post_url, array( 'body' => $body ) );

}
```

How do I select which forms to use this third party call on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Forms 3rd party Integration Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/forms-3rdparty-integration/screenshots/) allowed me to set up multiple third party forms and fully integrated with gravity forms.

Comment: How did you configure it? can't figure it out

Comment: I had an issue when using 'Advanced fields' like address fields in Gravity Forms. The field name would be 'input_1.3' and the id would be 'input_2_1_3'.
3rd Party Integrations mapping says you can use either name or id but it did not work when there was a dot in the name. Simply replacing the dot in name with underscore made it work. ex: input_1.3 -> input_1_3 ... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

The link you posted contains nearly all of the documentation you need to know about Gravity Forms. All you need to do is check the `$form` argument for any identifiers that the current form uses:

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) {
    if($form['title'] !== 'your-form-title'){ //Check the title
        return; //If the title doesn't match, don't POST
    }
    $post_url = 'http://thirdparty.com';
    $body = array(
        'first_name' => rgar( $entry, '1.3' ), 
        'last_name' => rgar( $entry, '1.6' ), 
        'message' => rgar( $entry, '3' ),
        );

    $request = new WP_Http();
    $response = $request->post( $post_url, array( 'body' => $body ) );

}
```

This checks the title beforehand to determine whether or not you actually want to post your information to your third party URL. While checking the title would certainly make your code more readable, I would actually recommend checking the ID of your forms for better reliability. [More information on Form Objects here](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/form-object/)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it exactly addresses Sam's question.

Comment: What do the 10, 2, 1.3, 1.6 & 3 values represent?

Comment: @joshmax The 10 and 2 in [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) represent the priority and number of arguments the callback function receives. [rgar](https://docs.gravityforms.com/rgar/) is a Gravity Forms helper function that retrieves a value out of an array by a given key. In this case, the `$entry` variable is keyed by field IDs, so those numbers represent those IDs.

Answer (score 2):

You can append the form id to the action name to hook into a specific form:

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_5', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
```

[The documentation for gform_after_submission can be found here](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_after_submission/).